# How to run Openerp 7 (Odoo) on Windows 7 from python source code?

Tags: python-2.7, pydev, openerp-7

I need to run openerp from source code in Windows enviroment.
I tried to run python source code with PyDev with eclipse. But got numerious errors such as "No module named babel.dates, win32serviceutil" etc.
I already installed Python 2.7 and Postgre on development machine.
I found old thread for Openerp 5.( https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+question/104901 ) But no luck with Openerp 7.

Comment: Here is a good article http://www.mindissoftware.com/2014/09/08/Odoo-PyCharm-Windows-installation/ which teach how to configure Odoo8 in Pycharm.

Comment: @user2681579 The link is dead. I need to run openerp 7 from source as well.